# Word for the person who has a favorite

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there is a word for a person who has a certain favorite. Consider the following example:

A person, Jack, has two favorite fruits: *apples* and *oranges*. Another person, Jill, also has two favorites: *bananas* and *apples*.

Now there are two persons with the *apple* in their list of favorite fruits. Said another way, the apple has two “favoritees”. Is this a good word for this relation, or is there a better one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest this is [favourer](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/favour?q=favourer#favour__44), as in "someone who favours something".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Andrew! Although I feel like “favourer” also is a bit of a hacky word, it does appear in the Oxford dictionaries, so I'll go with it for now. :-)

Comment: Or you could go with "preferrer."
 
Origin: 1350–1400;  Middle English  preferre  < Latin  praeferre  to bear before, set before, prefer, equivalent to prae-  pre- + ferre  to bear  

Related forms:  
pre·fer·red·ly  [pri-fur-id-lee, -furd-lee], adverb; pre·fer·red·ness, noun; pre·fer·rer, noun; un·pre·ferred, adjective 

Synonyms:  1. favor, fancy. 3. offer, proffer, tender. (from dictionaryBoss)

Comment: There isn't a single word for the person; but there's the fixed phrase _playing favorites_ for the trait of giving preference to some person for personal reasons, and also the fixed phrase _playing the favorite_ for the action of betting on a horse, player, or outcome that is the favorite in a contest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***The apple has a fanbase of 2.***

or

***Jack and Jill are apple fans.***

> From TheFreeDictionary.com:
>
> Fanbase [ˈfænˌbeɪs]
>
> n
>
> *"the body of admirers of a particular pop singer, football team, etc."* (or fruit!)

Comment: There are many great suggestions here, and I feel like I should have thought of many of them, especially this one! This is also the one most fitting to my situation and context, so I'll accept this as the answer to my question.

Thanks!

Comment: I might say "Jill is a fan of apples". "Jill is an Apple fan" would probably carry a connotation of being a fan of the company Apple (Nasdaq: AAPL) rather than of apples, the fruit.

Answer (score 3):

There are are a number of words which might fit well, depending on the context. Here's a few that strike me as particularly appropriate for your example:

- [***appreciator***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appreciator)
- [***fancier***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fancier)
- [***connoisseur***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/connoisseur)

For example,

> Jack and Jill are both apple *connoisseurs*.
>
> There were two apple *fanciers* in the room.

Answer (score 2):

There are many [relational antonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28semantics%29#Relational_antonyms) for *favorite* with different connotations; Wiktionary offers an extensive list as [synonyms of *enthusiast.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enthusiast#Synonyms)

Examples grouped by major connotations:

- *admirer, enthusiast, fan, fancier* for ordinary preferences
- *addict, fanatic, fiend, freak, geek, junkie, maniac* for unusual or extreme favorites
- *devotee, partisan, zealot* for extreme loyalty
- *aficionado, connoisseur, maven* for expertise

For the specific example given, I would use *apple fan* or *fancier.*